# Position with position absolute and translateY in displayFlex (DropDown item)

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I'm doing a popup menu signin and I'm trying to position my fontawesome icon in the same place as mine :: before

like this:

[image]

i want this:

[image]

but I got this:

[image]

**code:**

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="a">A</div>
  <div className="b">
    <div className="icon">
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        className="adjust"
        icon={faUser}
        size="2x"
        fixedWidth
        color="red"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="popup" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.App {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.b {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(calc(50% + 15px));
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.popup::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
  top: -15px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-architecture-oi51j

I'm trying to use display: flex and position absolute for this, but to no avail

Comment: okay , that was not clear, i did not notice

Comment: Sorry I tried to describe it in the best possible way, I'm not very good with English

so I tried to describe using the screnshots

Comment: don't be sorry, my english is also average ;)